# How to Get response when internet connection on/off for doing some task?

Tags: php, database, firebase, wamp, gprs

I have a software which is running in localhost for local shop. Also need internet for storing data in hosting server.[No domain]
Now i want to set a option when internet connection on/off take response to automatic backup database in localhost. when Internet connected it will automatically update in live server. [PHP]

Can you help me to develop this idea? please..

Comment: Did u try anything ??

Comment: I am making plan to develop this. I want to use PHP because other technology already develop like this. I will use firebase for online storage. Is it better or have you any more suggestion?